# How do I recover Xcode storyboard after stackview or label constraints get really large?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

It's happened a couple of times:  in an IB storyboard (Xcode Version 8.3.2) a nested stackview somehow got very large constraints.  The viewer expands out to 6.25% and I have to zoom back in to work on it.  Eventually Xcode crashes.  When I open the project again there is a warning about items being out of bounds (or something like that)  **I tried the "Resolve AutoLayout Issues" item but that didn't solve the problem**.

I eventually got the constraints sorted out and got the App running, but it eventually crashes back to the App Delegate.  I'm still new to the debugger and haven't been able to find the culprit that way, but I know which ViewController I'm in when it happens.

I was able to solve the problem in 1 of 2 ways:

1) Look for a UILabel with no text set in the Attributes Inspector (I was setting it in code)  But **putting a default value in the Attributes Inspector for all UILabels** seems to solve the problem.

2) In IB, **Completely rebuild the ViewController and all it's elements from scratch**.  This is the only way I was able to recover when one of the StackView elements got a very large dimension.

There must be a better way recover from this Xcode IB bug.